# Angular-UI Bootstrap Datepicker new date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui

I am using [Angular-UI Bootstrap Datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) directive for my project. What i want to do is, when i click to button, datepicker value is updating as expected, however, datepicker popup shows the wrong day. I am using `dd.MM.yyyy` format. It shows the `mm.dd.YYYY` instead of `dd.MM.yyyy`. is it a bug or am i missing something?

```
function appConfig(datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
        datepickerConfig.startingDay = 1;
        datepickerPopupConfig.datepickerPopup = 'dd.MM.yyyy';
}
```

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Fmcsz2rRDsi9U5eaeGz?p=preview)

Comment: Can you include your datepickerConfig ?

Comment: Configure your datepicker and popup.

Comment: @Mateutek i have already configured.

Comment: funny enough it seems to be working fine on my instance. Just to confirm we are still talking about formatting the date picker popup?

Comment: Could you share your instance? is it showing October 1st or January 10th?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date picker works just fine in my understanding. The problem is that you change the value in your controller with `this.date = "01.10.2015"`.

You might consider doing this with `this.date = new Date(2015,9,1)` because date is of type date in the background. The directive cares for the transformation of these formats.

EDIT:
If you want to stick to your way, you could use a parse function like this (found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945113/howto-create-a-new-date-in-javascript-from-a-non-standard-date-format)):

```
function parseDate(input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  return new Date(parts[2], parts[1]-1, parts[0]);
}
```

And the call:

```
this.date = parseDate("01.10.2015")
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qmtAoHutR1OhFuIyNsUC?p=preview) is your updated plunker.

Comment: I have a json format `beOnLeaveDate: 15.07.2015`. I decided to change date format of json to  The ISO 8601 syntax. So it works as expected. Thanks for your answers by the way :)