# javascript: new Date("31.12.2015") returning Invalid Date

Tags: javascript

In javascript programming I am using new `Date(aDate)`.

`aDate` can be in any format like `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` or `yyyy-MM-dd` etc.

But when using format as `dd.MM.yyyy`, all the dates are working except 31.12.2015. `new Date("31.12.2015")` returning the error `Invalid Date`.

All other formats are working fine.Why 31.12.2015 showing error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [howto create a new Date() in Javascript from a non-standard date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945113/howto-create-a-new-date-in-javascript-from-a-non-standard-date-format)

Comment: `new Date(str)` is required to accept certain formats such as ISO; other than that, what it supports is up to the browser, and you are better off not depending on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse these non standard date formats by using to following code:

```
var da = '31.12.2015'.split('.').map(function(d) {
  return parseInt(d);
});
var d = new Date(da[2], da[1] - 1, da[0]);
```

Or a time formatting library like [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/) if you're doing a lot of things with dates and times and need to account for edge cases.

```
var d = moment('31.12.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY');
```

Comment: Need to adjust month by 1.

Comment: Just realized that. Thanks! @torazaburo.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just 31, is every day greater than 12, bcz is expecting `MM.dd.yyyy`, there are some solutions on this similar post:

[How to create a new Date() in Javascript from a non-standard date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945113/howto-create-a-new-date-in-javascript-from-a-non-standard-date-format)